# Difficulty understanding natural transformation notation

Tags: category-theory, monads

I'm trying to fully understand the conditions for a monad as they are written in category theory.  Left and right identity are expressed as follows:
$$\mu \circ \eta T = \mu \circ T \eta = id_T$$
Where $C$ is a category, $T:C \rightarrow C$, $\mu:T\circ T \rightarrow T$ and $\eta : id_C \rightarrow T$. If I understand correctly,
$$\eta T : id_C \circ T \rightarrow T \circ T$$
$$T \eta : T \circ id_C \rightarrow T \circ T$$
But $T$ left or right composed with $id_C$ should just be $T$... which would mean that $\eta T$ and $T\eta$ have the same type signature. What distinguishes them?

Comment: This question might be helpful : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1755429/composing-functors-with-natural-transformations/1755436

Comment: The way you have written your first identity seems a bit weird to me : $\mu \circ \eta T$ and $\mu \circ T$ are natural transformations $T\Rightarrow T$, but to me $id_C$ should be the identity functor on $C$. Did you mean to write $id_T$?

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yes, I fixed it just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it helps a lot to translate other concepts into this algebraic notation. For example:

- Use juxtaposition $Fx$ and $Ff$ to give the value of a functor $F$ at an object $x$ or a morphism $f$
- Use juxtaposition $\eta x$ to give the component of a natural transformation $\eta$ at the object $x$

In fact, if you express an object as a functor $1 \to \mathcal{C}$ and an arrow as a natural transformation between such functors, then the above isn't even a translation; the horizontal composite $\eta x$ is literally the arrow corresponding to $\eta_x$.

Since we usually understand natural transformations by their action on objects, we can see their difference: the products involved in the two formulas $\eta T x$ and $T \eta x$ are in different orders.  Using this to help compute the components of both natural transformations in more familiar notation:

- $(\eta T)_x = \eta T x = \eta T(x) = \eta_{T(x)} $
- $(T \eta)_x = T \eta x = T \eta_x = T(\eta_x) $

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $\eta T, T\eta : T\to T\circ T$. However, $(\eta T)_x = \eta_{Tx}$, whereas $(T\eta)_x = T(\eta_x)$ so *a priori* there's no reason they should be equal for an arbitrary functor.

In particular, this is true for a monad.

If you want to understand (or at least easily remember) the axioms for a monad, try to think of them as saying "$T$ is a monad if and only if it is a monoid in the monoidal category $(C^C, \circ)$"

Comment: Did you mean to write $\eta T, T\eta : T \rightarrow T \circ T$?

Comment: Yes sorry, let me edit that

Comment: Ok the first part did help me, but the "If you want to understand" bit that followed was really confusing for me.

Comment: @IvanPerez Do you know what a monoid is ? Now if I give you a monoidal category $(D,\otimes)$ with $\otimes$ an associative bifunctor, do you know what a "monoid in $D$" is ? if yes, then apply this to $D= C^C, \otimes = \circ$ : a monad is a monoid in $C^C$

Comment: I do know what a monoid is, but that is a long chain of concepts and notation (monoidal category, then bifunctor, etc.) that does not really help IMO.

Comment: bifunctor is in the definition of monoidal category. And if you're not comfortable with these, it might be a good idea to start working on them before learning about monads

Comment: Understanding what a monoidal category is, or having associated a meaning to that term, is completely unnecessary for understanding what a monad is. If you do know what they are, then relating those concepts may help, but it is by far not a requirement.

Comment: @IvanPerez : I said it might be a good idea, not that they are a requirement; though I do find it quite illuminating. In any case, if you're not familiar with the concepts in question, reading the last paragraph should clearly not confuse you, as you could just dismiss it; on the other hand if you *are* familiar with those concepts, the last paragraph can be extremely useful. I know it was for me in that situation.

Comment: That's really not how explanations work.

Comment: @IvanPerez : It is, when you don't kniw the asker's background : provide what you think might be relevant, so long as the answer to the specific question is accessible to anyone asking the question. I don't know why you're insisting on this, when all I did was provide supplementary information