# Sandwich natural transformation between two functors

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, functors, natural-transformations

In the [Kleisli adjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleisli_category#Kleisli_adjunction) we have:

$G\varepsilon F = \mu$ where $\varepsilon$ is a natural transformation called the counit.

How exactly is $G\varepsilon F$ defined? I understand $G\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon F$ but not the sandwiched form.

Followup question: [Counit of the Kleisli adjunction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3011366/counit-of-the-kleisli-adjunction)

Comment: If I call $\varepsilon F$ $\alpha$ and ask what is $G\alpha$, do you understand it then? It's compositional. There is, of course, a coherence constraint you could verify. Namely that $G\alpha = \beta F$ where $\beta = G\varepsilon$. Incidentally, I personally prefer representing right whiskering by subscripting, i.e. $G\varepsilon_F$.

Comment: @DerekElkins I posted a followup https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3011366/counit-of-the-kleisli-adjunction

Comment: For reference of future readers, the construction that the notation is supposed to imply is called "whiskering" (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/whiskering) which is basically the same as horizontal composition (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Godement+product) with the identity natural transformation of a functor.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1755429/composing-functors-with-natural-transformations